# Angular change an element in Ngfor within a table

Tags: angular, ngfor

Hi there I have a table where I want to change an element in a table.

Here is my code. I want to change the color of a car and then update it. If I follow my code, car.color remains the same. I've tried to use Ngmodel within the input type but it changes all the elements of my list.

What can I do ?

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars">
    <td><input type="text value="{{car.color}}"></td>
    <td>{{ car.brand }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.id }}</td>
    <td"><button type="button" (click)="onUpdateCar(car)"> update </button></td>
</tr>
```

Edit:

here is the ts file which should, I hope send an update version of my car object

```
onUpdateCar(car) {
      this.carService.updateCar(car).subscribe();
      }
```

Comment: Where is the code that you try to change the value? Please show that :)

Comment: Please share your ts file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the value attribute on the textbox, instead, you can use the `ngModel` as below:-

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars">
    <td><input type="text [(ngModel)]="car.color"></td>
    <td>{{ car.brand }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.id }}</td>
    <td"><button type="button" (click)="onUpdateCar(car)">Update</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It does work as it updates the right car. But when I open my page all the <td>car.color</td> display the same thing, ie the color of the last car of the table.

Comment: @Jean Then you need to update the `cars` array as well to keep the state of the car.